# Two divs (one with tinymce) to share a scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, tinymce

I have these two divs:

```
<div id="ing" style="position:relative;">
     <div id="comm" style="position: absolute; width: 27% !important; height: 141px; right: 18px; top: 1px; ">
     </div>
</div>
```

And then in JS I set tinymce to the "ingredients" div. How to make these two divs share a scrollbar like this: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/hThsx/

Comment: Won't the "comm" div disappear when you start TinyMCE?

Comment: @Thariama Maybe you would know?

Comment: Put a wrapper div around the thing and let that have the scrollbar.

Comment: comm will be the html source element of your editor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem her is that your editor uses a contenteditable iframe with an own document.
So this iframe has an own scrollbar and you cannot do anything about it except adjusting the iframe dimensions to the inner documents dimensions. In this case there won't be a scrollbar for the editor iframe.

Now you may follow Cobra_Fasts idea of putting a wrapper div around your two divs and let it have a scrollbar.